# Prevent users from Closing a Work Item before resolving it in Azure DevOps

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to prevent users from directly closing the task without resolving it in azure devops(vsts).Is there a way to put a constraint on the states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define a constraint. In Azure DevOps, you can create your custom rule: [Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops).
As example:

1. Add custom field (like Close Resolution) - [Add and manage fields for an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops)

[image]

2. In the Resolve state, set some value for it - [Add a custom rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops#add-a-custom-rule)

[image]

3. Make it required for the Close state - [Add a custom rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops#add-a-custom-rule)

[image]

Comment: What rule can be added for the third point i.e. Making it required for close state?

Comment: @Samuel I`ve added screenshots for each step. I do not have the Resolve state in my process template. So just replace Active to Resolve in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for, frankly, doesn't make sense.

You can't save something with validation errors. You can close it without saving. What other options are there? Locking someone into a form is terrible UX design, to the extent that if it were possible, it would be called a bug. And no matter what, your users can always close their browser.